# How do i clip the border of an area?

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I want to clip the parts of an area such that a path which goes through it proceed at the border of the area. It should look like that but there must be a better solution instead of cutting with that rectangle.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw   (4,0) node (11) {}
        (2,0.1) node (12) {}
        (4.4,3.2) node (13) {}
        (2,3.6) node (14) {} 
        (4.8,1.3) node (15) {}
        (1.1,1.8) node (16) {} 
        (3.2,1.8) node (17) {}
;

\draw  [line width=0.10mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(15)(17)(16)};
\draw [fill=black!40, black!40] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3,2.2)(3.6,2.3)(3.7,1.8)(3.5,1.5)(3,1.4)(2.8,1.8)};
\draw  [line width=0.125mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(11)(17)(14)};
\draw [fill=black!30, black!30] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2.2)(3.5,2.2)(3.6,1.9)(3.3,1.5)(3,1.5)(2.9,1.8)}; 
\draw  [line width=0.15mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(12)(17)(13)};  
\draw [fill=black!20, black!20] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2)(3.4,2.1)(3.4,1.8)(3.2,1.6)(3.0245,1.579)(3,1.8)}; 
\clip [rotate=52](3.0653,-1.4084) rectangle (3.7509,-1.6064);
\draw [black!100] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2)(3.4,2.1)(3.4,1.8)(3.2,1.6)(3.0245,1.579)(3,1.8)}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I failed to make clear what i want. The solution should work for all 3 path and look like that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clip according to existing paths/nodes like `\clip  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(12)(17)(13)} -- (15) -- (11) -- cycle;` although this is a slightly tighter clipping than would be desired.

[image]

With a little bit of manual adjustment (via the TikZ `calc` library) on the midpoint of the `plot` we can get a bit closer to a natural clipping with `\clip  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(12)($(17)+(-0.005,0.005)$)(13)} -- (15) -- (11) -- cycle;`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\draw   (4,0) node (11) {}
        (2,0.1) node (12) {}
        (4.4,3.2) node (13) {}
        (2,3.6) node (14) {} 
        (4.8,1.3) node (15) {}
        (1.1,1.8) node (16) {} 
        (3.2,1.8) node (17) {}
;
\draw  [line width=0.10mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(15)(17)(16)};
\draw [fill=black!40, black!40] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3,2.2)(3.6,2.3)(3.7,1.8)(3.5,1.5)(3,1.4)(2.8,1.8)};
\draw  [line width=0.125mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(11)(17)(14)};
\draw [fill=black!30, black!30] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2.2)(3.5,2.2)(3.6,1.9)(3.3,1.5)(3,1.5)(2.9,1.8)}; 
\draw  [line width=0.15mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(12)(17)(13)};  
\draw [fill=black!20, black!20] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2)(3.4,2.1)(3.4,1.8)(3.2,1.6)(3.0245,1.579)(3,1.8)}; 
\clip  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(12)($(17)+(-0.005,0.005)$)(13)} -- (15) -- (11) -- cycle;
\draw [black!100] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2)(3.4,2.1)(3.4,1.8)(3.2,1.6)(3.0245,1.579)(3,1.8)}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Applying this to all the crossing paths requires appropriate scoping of the different `\clip`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\draw   (4,0) node (11) {}
        (2,0.1) node (12) {}
        (4.4,3.2) node (13) {}
        (2,3.6) node (14) {} 
        (4.8,1.3) node (15) {}
        (1.1,1.8) node (16) {} 
        (3.2,1.8) node (17) {}
;

\draw  [line width=0.10mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(15)(17)(16)};
\draw [fill=black!40, black!40] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3,2.2)(3.6,2.3)(3.7,1.8)(3.5,1.5)(3,1.4)(2.8,1.8)};
\draw  [line width=0.125mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(11)(17)(14)};
\draw [fill=black!30, black!30] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2.2)(3.5,2.2)(3.6,1.9)(3.3,1.5)(3,1.5)(2.9,1.8)};
\draw  [line width=0.15mm] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(12)(17)(13)}; 
\draw [fill=black!20, black!20] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2)(3.4,2.1)(3.4,1.8)(3.2,1.6)(3.0245,1.579)(3,1.8)}; 

\begin{scope}
\clip plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(15)($(17)+(0,-0.005)$)(16)} -- (13) -- cycle;
\draw [black!100] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3,2.2)(3.6,2.3)(3.7,1.8)(3.5,1.5)(3,1.4)(2.8,1.8)};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(11)($(17)+(-0.005,-0.005)$)(14)} -- (13) -- (15) -- cycle;
\draw [black!100] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2.2)(3.5,2.2)(3.6,1.9)(3.3,1.5)(3,1.5)(2.9,1.8)}; 
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(12)($(17)+(-0.005,0.005)$)(13)} -- (15) -- (11) -- cycle;
\draw [black!100] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(3.2,2)(3.4,2.1)(3.4,1.8)(3.2,1.6)(3.0245,1.579)(3,1.8)};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It work for 1 but if I try it like that for all 3 path I can't get it work. I didn't make it clear that it should work for all path but I edited my question now.

Comment: @jigsawl Probably that's due to `\clip` affecting everything in the same `scope` as itself.